# UIToolBar is Transparent

Tags: ios, swift, uitoolbar

When I add a UIToolBar, it appears to be transparent. However, I do not want this to happen. Here is my code:

```
var done = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done, target: self, action: Selector("done"))

    if let font = UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 17.0) {
        done.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: font], forState: .Normal)
    }
    toolBar.items = [done]
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
    self.birthdayTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Having come across this issue myself I found that the toolbar must either be instantiated with a non-zero frame, or have `sizeToFit` called on it.

e.g.

```
    let tb = UIToolbar()
    tb.translucent = false
    tb.items = [UIBarButtonItem.init(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil), UIBarButtonItem.init(title: "A button", style: .Plain, target: self, action: Selector("someAction:"))]
    tb.sizeToFit()
    userField?.inputAccessoryView = tb
```

or

```
    let tb = UIToolbar(CGRectMake(0,0,view.frame.width,44))
    tb.translucent = false
    tb.items = [UIBarButtonItem.init(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil), UIBarButtonItem.init(title: "A button", style: .Plain, target: self, action: Selector("someAction:"))]
    userField?.inputAccessoryView = tb
```

Answer (score 2):

try this code for UIToolBar Transparent :

```
self.toolbar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(),
                                forToolbarPosition: UIBarPosition.Any,
                                barMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
self.toolbar.setShadowImage(UIImage(),
                            forToolbarPosition: UIBarPosition.Any)
```

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear before. I don't want my toolBar to be transparent. For some reason, the code I provided produces a transparent toolBar.

Answer (score 0):

This should disable the translucency/transpacency effect

```
toolbar.translucent = false
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I tried this, but it still has a transparent/translucent effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
```

and make sure `toolBar.translucent = false`

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin (similar for swift)

```
toolbar.Translucent = false;
toolbar.BarTintColor = color;
```